# django using provider url patch

Tags: django, redirect

I am developing a django site that ,on my development environment, is accessed by the url localhost:8000.
The url is automatically redirect to the url localhost:8000/accounts/login and, after login, to localhost:8000/iform/list.

After deployed on my webserver, the app now is called icontrol, so, on the configuration panel of my provider, I set it to respond to the url www.mydomain.com/icontrol.

When using the same files for development and deploy, after the login, instead  redirect to www.mydomain.com/icontrol/iform/list, for example, its trying to redirecting to to www.mydomain.com/iform/list.

How to make it work correctly on both environments?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways it can be done.  The easiest, and most correct way for what you are doing, is to use the [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) setting.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/icontrol/iform/list'
```

If you want more fine control over it, you can probably override the get_success_url like they have done [here](https://coderwall.com/p/sll1kw/django-auth-class-based-views-login-and-logout).

Since you seem to want to use a static URL, I would suggest the first way though.